# How do I search Google Drive API by date?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive V3 API to manipulate files in a folder.

What I am currently doing to list all my files is like so:

```
const data = await drive.files.list({ q: `'${folderId}' in parents` });
console.log(data.files);
```

So basically I'm using a service account to query a folder for all its files. I'd also like to query for date. Something like `createdTime < ${date}`.

Reading through a few posts on this site and the documentation, there doesn't seem to be such a feature to do so. I can see that there is the option to use `modifiedTime`, however when I try to use it, everything just freezes up and the script run indefinitely.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can query this?

**Edit 21/10/12 11:08**

So I tried doing the following per Taneike's suggestion:

```
console.log('1') //this logs in the console
const data = drive.files.list({
    q: `'${folderId}' in parents and createdTime > 2012-06-04T12:00:00-08:00`,
});
//unreachable code below
console.log('2') //this doesn't log
console.log(data) //this doesn't log
```

So basically my script will run indefinitely, and I have to manually end the script. `drive.files.list` won't return anything.

Comment: About `query a folder for all its files`, in your situation, the folder has the subfolders and you want to retrieve all files in the subfolders?

Comment: So at the moment, I am able to retrieve all the files in 'Folder A' by using `{q: ''${folderID}' in parents'}`. What I would like to do is also query it by date. 
So for example, `{q: ''${folderId}' in parents and createdTime < ${date}'}`.

Comment: Could you paste the result of `console.log(q)` with `createdTime` added?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood that you wanted to retrieve the files by `createdTime` in the specific folder, and the specific folder has no subfolders. So I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and replying, I apologize.

Comment: @emptyhua there are no results, the query runs indefinitely.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `So I tried doing the following per Taneike's suggestion:`, unfortunately, it seems that your additional script doesn't correctly reflect my proposed script. Please confirm it again. Please modify to ``const data = await drive.files.list({q: `'${folderId}' in parents and createdTime > '2012-06-04T12:00:00-08:00'`});`` and `console.log(data.data)`, and test it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought that `createdTime < date` can be used. And, when I saw your script, I noticed that there is a modification point. And, from your replying of `So at the moment, I am able to retrieve all the files in 'Folder A' by using {q: ''${folderID}' in parents'}. What I would like to do is also query it by date. So for example, {q: ''${folderId}' in parents and createdTime < ${date}'}. –`, I thought that there might be also a modification point.

When the above points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
const data = await drive.files.list({q: `'${folderId}' in parents and createdTime < '${date}'`}).catch((err) => console.log(err.errors));
console.log(data.data);
```

- In this case, please set the value of `date` like `2012-06-04T12:00:00-08:00` as [RFC3339 format](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339).

#### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search query terms and operators](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms)

Comment: According the your answer and the documentation, it should be working, however it doesn't seem to be working. I edited my main post to show what I tried. Basically the query will run indefinitely unless I manually stop the script from running.

Comment: @ffx292 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In your added script, `'${folderId}' in parents and createdTime > 2012-06-04T12:00:00-08:00` is used. In this case, `2012-06-04T12:00:00-08:00` is not enclosed by the single quotes. In my answer, I have modified it. This is an important point. So, when you modify it to `'${folderId}' in parents and createdTime > '2012-06-04T12:00:00-08:00'`, what result will you obtain? And, in order to retrieve the file list in your script, please use `console.log(data.data)`.

Comment: @ffx292 By the way, I cannot understand ` the query will run indefinitely unless I manually stop the script from running.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Oh, so I'm running this using NodeJS, so basically when do `node index.js`, it will not stop until I press CMD+C to stop it.

Comment: It works! I realized that I didn't put quotation marks around the `${date}`! いつもありがとうございます！